# Why the directory ~/.local/lib is behind the /usr/local/lib in my sys.path?

Tags: python

The OS version is Ubuntu 16.04 and the Python version is 3.5.2.
My shell is bash.
When I typed sys.path in my shell, the outputs is as follows:

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyYAML-4.2b4-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',  '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/data1/fujiayi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload']
```

I think the order of my sys.path is a little strange because .local dir is behind the /usr/local.
Why is this happening? 
What should I do if I want to prioritize the .local dir?